# sorting scientific number with sort 8.21

Tags: linux, sorting, exponential

I need to sort this file by column 3 then 2 then 1

```
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-01 1.2500e-01 5.0521e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-01 1.2500e-02 5.0259e+00
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-02 1.2500e-02 4.9924e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-02 2.7500e-03 4.9657e+00
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-03 2.7500e-03 5.0267e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-02 2.7500e-03 5.0003e+00
```

So far I was using sort (version 8.13)

```
sort -k 3,3g -k 2,2g -k 1,1g file
```

to obtain the correct output:

```
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-03 2.7500e-03 5.0267e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-02 2.7500e-03 4.9657e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-02 2.7500e-03 5.0003e+00
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-02 1.2500e-02 4.9924e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-01 1.2500e-02 5.0259e+00
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-01 1.2500e-01 5.0521e+00
```

Since I have upgraded my system (sort is now version 8.21), the above command gives me

```
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-01 1.2500e-02 5.0259e+00
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-01 1.2500e-01 5.0521e+00
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-02 1.2500e-02 4.9924e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-02 2.7500e-03 4.9657e+00
9.2500e-01 9.7500e-02 2.7500e-03 5.0003e+00
9.2500e-02 9.7500e-03 2.7500e-03 5.0267e+00
```

Any idea about what is going on and how to do this?

Comment: I've not got 8.21 on hand at the moment, but you seem to be presenting a good case for 'bug introduced since 8.13'.  Before reporting it as a bug, check the latest version of GNU coreutils (8.22 rather than 8.21).  _[...time passeth...]_ Hmmm; doesn't reproduce for me with 8.22. It would be more convincing if I had reproduced it in 8.21, but I'm feeling lazy (though it really wouldn't take all that long to do). _[...more time passeth...]_ It doesn't repro in 8.21 either.  Check your locale settings.  Maybe set LANG=C and/or LC_ALL=C and try that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan, indeed the problem is solved by using export LC_ALL=C.